# Browsing the .NET Framework source code from Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I know that [I can set up Visual Studio to debug through the .NET framework source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20150822081658/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx).

But is there a way that I can browse the code while NOT debugging - i.e., being able to press F12 or "Go to definition"?

I thought that if that feature isn't built into Visual Studio then there may be a plug-in that might add it?

Comment: This feature can only work when you have the projects loaded in a solution so that IntelliSense can parse them.  Clearly you don't want a solution that builds all the .NET framework assemblies.

Comment: Link is broken, here's the Wayback version: https://web.archive.org/web/20150822081658/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just discovered this extension that pretty much addresses my problem. The only thing is that it opens the source in the browser rather than in Visual Studio, but it's no big deal because even in the browser you can click the source code to navigate to types etc.

It was [presented on Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingTheNewRoslynpoweredNETFrameworkReferenceSource.aspx) a couple of days ago:

> Community member and fabulous coder [Schabse Laks](http://slaks.net/) has created a Visual Studio extension for VS2010, 2012, and 2013! This extension sends calls to Go To Definition (or pressing F12 on a symbol) directly to the code online (when it's .NET Framework code, not yours).
>
> You can [download this companion "Ref12" Visual Studio Extension now](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f89b27c5-7d7b-4059-adde-7ccc709fa86e)! Just Goto Definition on any .NET type we have source for and it'll launch your default browser so you can explore the .NET Framework source yourself! Thanks Schabse!

Update:

As per the comments, for VS 2022 and .NET Core, use this fork of the extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EfreyKong.Ref12-VS2022

Comment: Doesn't work with webapi either by the looks of things

Comment: can i check my .net framework version in my git Hub source code??

Comment: Brilliant! I installed `Ref12 VS2022` (in Visual Studio 2022) and, bada-bing, bada-boom, clicking on an ASP.NET Core thing and pressing F12 takes me to a nifty online source code browser with the code for the ASP.NET Core thing displayed.

Comment: The original Github Repo by Schabse Laks had not been updated for several years, and has been forked by Efrey Kong, and the extension updated to support Visual Studio 2022, and .Net Core. This new version is also named Ref12, and can be found on the Visual Studio Marketplace, here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EfreyKong.Ref12-VS2022

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not support .Net core in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 27):

There is a very new feature in **Visual Studio 2017** version **15.6**

You can see decompiled source code without any plugin!  Btw, Ref12 doesn't work for VS2017.

**Tools** > **Options** , expand **Text Editor** > **C#** > **Advanced**, and enable "**Enable navigation to decompiled sources (experimental)**".

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2017#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c

Comment: Yes, it's a good feature but it is showing decompiled code, not showing the original source code (that is available online).

Answer (score 18):

With ReSharper it's possible to browse .NET sources by enabling ReSharper -> Options -> Tools -> External Sources -> Navigation to Sources.
After enabling this option new menu item "Navigate To -> Decompiled Sources" appears by right click on type/method/whatever.
Navigation also works with F12 for me.

Comment: It only shows the interface information but not the actual source code (contents of the methods) itself. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. It works now. I guess I had to rebuild ;-)
Sweet! Now I can F12 into .NET sources!

Comment: Hi @Xan-KunClark-Davis, how did you start the code browsing? Do you ctrl-click a type? I rebuilt the project and it still shows the decompiled class.

Comment: @OgrishMan Sorry, my bad. I actually see the code ReSharper decompiles with the help of downloaded symbol files. It show more than just an interface, but is definately NOT the real source code (e.g.: no comments in it). Again, sorry for the confusion and for getting you hopes up. I think this should be clarified in the answer.

Comment: Beware before installing Resharper. This is a paid tool, and though there is a trial period, using it requires you to sign in using an IntelliJ/social media account to provide them your email and personal details, and also agree to an end user license agreement on first run.

Answer (score 6):

I downloaded the .NET Framework source code from here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx.

Since I am working with .NET 4.0, I chose ".Net/4" from the list.  (What is ".NET/8.0" in that list?  No idea.)

I wrote some scripts to rearrange the bloody mess they give us:

- Into a reasonable hierarchy of directories;
- To remove duplicated code (why is every file doubled, or was my install bad?);
- Rename all top-level namespaces to not conflict with native ones baked into Intellisense.
- Example: System.Windows.Controls -> xSystem.Windows.Controls

Then follow these steps:

1. Create a new Visual Studio project of type "Class Library"
2. Remove all references -- yes, even the system ones.
3. Drag/drop all of your massaged .NET code into the root of your project.
4. Wait about 30 minutes for VS processing.  VS will appear to freeze; be patient.

Intellisense/ReSharper still complains about heaps of problems, but now I can right click and select "Go to Declaration/Implementation".

Visual Studio is about 600MB with this project loaded.

Comment: could you share your scripts or your final .sln file?

Comment: yes, would be great to share the final result, so all others does not have to do the same 'boring' procedure of renaming and so on.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

**1.** Choose menu: **TOOLS \ Extensions and Updates...**
[image]

**2.** Choose **Visual Studio Gallery \  Search Results**. Search term: `Ref12`.
[image]

**3.** Download then install.
[image]

**4.** Restart Visual Studio.

**5.** Try: Click mouse on Class or method, press <kbd>F12</kbd> and see result at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: Thanks, but this is a duplicate of the answer I posted 1 year before.

Comment: @XavierPoinas, That is right. However this post answers the question in another perspective. Someone understands answers better including **steps** or **images**. Others prefer raw text.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this but supposedly the code is publicly available:

[Edit]

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: Sure - that's what VS uses in debug mode (when set up as in the above link). But how do I set up VS so that it can find and display the source code for me when I am not debugging?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [.NET Mass Downloader](http://csharpopensource.com/dotnetmassdownloader.aspx), but I think the straightforward answer to your question is, no.

However I now see Microsoft has made the code more easily downloadable.

Nevertheless note that even for your own code, when not debugging, unless you have the project open, VS does not help you locate source code (even though when you find it yourself break points will work when you start debugging again, if the `.pdb` files correspond).

Answer (score 0):

## VS2022

Old thread, new VS ☺

Go to
**Tools > Options**
then
**Text Editor > C# > Advanced**
under
**Go To Definition**
select
**Enable navigation to Source Link and Embedded Sources**

[image: Screenshot of Go To Definition section]

### Also

Make sure that under
**Debugging > General**
source server and Source Link are enabled.

[image]

### Resharper

Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work in conjunction with ReSharper, since then it always decompiles. So I had to **disable ReSharper**'s navigation feature completely.