# Windows Forms - no C# source code?

Tags: winforms, definition

I'm new to Windows Forms.
I'm not fully understanding why can't I see methods definitions? Am I only allowed to look at declarations?

For example, there is

```
public class ListBox : ListControl
```

I want to see how its method is working(source code, not Microsoft comments):

```
public override string ToString();
```

I only see this definition and when I'm pressing "Go to definition", it transfers me to this declaration.

Can someone please explain is System.Windows.Forms code is "hidden" ? Can someone describe what's the idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browsing the .NET Framework source code from Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695569/browsing-the-net-framework-source-code-from-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net is closed source so you cant see exact codes, not only winforms you cant see any class definition of framework. If you want you can use [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the official source code released by Microsoft since December 2018 and [can be seen on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms). There is an alternative (buggy) [implementation from Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.Windows.Forms).