# View .Net Framework source code without Visual Studio

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm going through an MVC course and the instructor explains how the classes/objects are related and how the hierarchy is structured.

I thought if i could view this information visually it would help and give clarity so wondered is there a way to view .Net Frameworks source code without Visual Studio?

I looked at [Browsing the .NET Framework source code from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695569/browsing-the-net-framework-source-code-from-visual-studio) which requires Re-Sharper and thats a paid product and some of the links on that page no longer work. Searched on google and most links are broken.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can view all source on [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/), though I think you're going to overwhelm yourself by doing this and not sure what you're hoping to achieve

Comment: Thanks for that, as an example i would like to know more about the ActionResult class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) when searching it brings up nothing?

Comment: An alternative to ReSharper would be to use ILSpy (free) to look at the System.Web.Mvc namespace. The issue with using Google currently is that ASP.NET Core is the new and improved/supported version of ASP.NET which is open source, so any searching of `ActionResult` will yield GitHub links for ASP.NET Core.