# How to download source code directly instead of decompile local .dll files for .net core when I click Go to Declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, jetbrains-ide, rider

When I want to read the source code of .net core, I click Go to Declaration button and on the Windows edition, I get the decompile code by the local .dll file.
[image: Windows Edition]
But when I do the same behavior on the rider for macOS edition, Looks like I get the real source code from Internet and this edition can get comment that very useful for me.
[image]
So I wonder know how to change the default behavior for Windows edition to get real source code? I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695569/browsing-the-net-framework-source-code-from-visual-studio) ?

Comment: Thanks! But this way only decompiled base local .dll files without comment, I hope it can directly download from Internet.

Comment: You can find manually in https://source.dot.net/ or in github