# Visual Studio IDE 2022 - how to disable navigation to decompiled sources

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've enabled 'navigation to decompiled sources' in my `Visual Studio IDE` according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695569/browsing-the-net-framework-source-code-from-visual-studio/52605830#52605830).

[image]

Now I can't disable it. Turning off `Enable navigation to decompiled sources` option does not helps.

Please help me! I want to see [metadata](https://I%20want%20to%20see%20metadata%20instead%20of%20decompiled%20source%20definitions.) instead of `decompiled source definitions` again.

Comment: Do you by chance have Resharper installed? That has its own settings for this.

Comment: no, I do not use Resharper.

Comment: I don't know, but I would try deleting all caches (the path to the cache file can be seen when the file is open). Maybe it uses the decompiled sources because they're already there.

Comment: @PMF I've deleted "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared" and now I can see 'metadata' instead of 'decompiled source definitions' but VS stopped compiling :(

Comment: @PMF deleting the caches (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\SourceServer) does not helps

Comment: The first part was bad (reinstall dotnet to fix that). That folder contains the .net runtime installation.

Comment: You should disable not **Enable navigation to decompiled sources**, but **Enable navigation to Source Link and Embedded sources**, because a decompile source is Source Link.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria please answer your replay and I will mark as 'Answerd'. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable also **Enable navigation to Source Link and Embedded sources** addition to **Enable navigation to decompiled sources**, because a decompile source is Source Link.

[image]